# Perforce can't edit file as it says it is already opened, however 'p4 opened' reports otherwise

Tags: perforce

i'm having this situation

when i try to run `p4 edit <file>`, it says

```
- can't edit (already opened on this client)
```

However, when i ran `p4 opened <file>` (with the `-a` and `-x` option), it says

```
-  - file(s) not opened on this client.
```

I'm now left in this limbo state.

- I can not check out the file,
- i can not revert the file,
- and i can not check in the file.

How can i fix this? And what happened actually?

Comment: Maybe it's opened by a different client on this machine? Try `p4 opened -a | grep <file>` and see if you can figure out whether a different client has the file opened.

Comment: @BryanPendleton sorry, i editted my question. I actually tried both -a and -x options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First -- double check that all the file paths you stripped out of your question actually match each other.  The *legitimate* way to get this error is if you're trying to edit a *depot* file that's already open under a different *local* path on the same client (because you opened it and then changed your client view), and you're trying to reopen the same depot file via the "new" local path while it still has pending changes in the previous location.  Make sure you're running `p4 opened <file>` and `p4 revert <file>` on the *same exact depot path* that was returned by the `can't edit` error.

Once that's eliminated:

This error being thrown when it shouldn't is usually a symptom of an internal database inconsistency in the Perforce server -- the depot file is recorded in the db.locks table as being open on your client, but the corresponding client file isn't in the db.working table.

The easiest way to fix this is for the admin to run `p4d -xf 925` on the server root; this is a repair command that looks for this exact inconsistency and should repair it by pruning out unmatched db.locks entries.

`p4d -xx` will also fix it (this command scans for a set of different inconsistencies and writes a journal patch file to repair them).

Comment: Hi Sam, thank a lot. `p4d -xf` seems to fixed that issue. One question though, may i know what the `925` means? And where can i read more about this documentation?

Comment: 925 is a reference to an internal bug number corresponding to this issue (`job000925`).  :P  This command and a couple other like it are described in `p4 help undoc`.

Comment: Thanks Sam. That is really informative and helpful :)

Comment: The same thing happened to me when I switched "classical" workspace with opened files to a stream. -xf 925 did not help me, I had to delete the workspace and then recreate it.

Comment: @martin were you running the two commands on the same *depot path*?  Switching a classic client to a stream client would be a very easy way to get in the situation I described where the local paths get confused.

Comment: @Samwise well, I think I did, but then what do I know. I am fairly certain I tried running *revert* on the same *depot path* I was trying to open for edit.

Comment: If it ever happens again, make sure to keep track of the exact commands you ran.   If you'd run into the same problem described here, I don't think deleting the client and re-creating it would have worked (the "orphaned" record would get missed by the client deletion exactly like it got missed by the revert).